# Parsing a JSON array BEGIN_ARRAY but was NAME

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm parsing this JSON stream

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "count":1,
    "data":{
        "1000194290":[
            {
                "statistics":{
                    "wins":472,
                    "all":{
                        "spotted":0,
                        "hits":0,
                        "battle_avg_xp":0,
                        "draws":0,
                        "wins":472,
                        "losses":0,
                        "capture_points":0,
                        "battles":894,
                        "damage_dealt":0,
                        "hits_percents":0,
                        "damage_received":0,
                        "shots":0,
                        "xp":0,
                        "frags":0,
                        "survived_battles":0,
                        "dropped_capture_points":0
                    },
                    "battles":894
                },
                "mark_of_mastery":4,
                "tank_id":3649
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

I attempt to start an array at 1000194290 but get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NAME at line 1 column 35
```

My parsing class looks like this

```
public List<TankStats> readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"))) {
        return readTankIdStep(reader);
    }
}

public List<TankStats> readTankIdStep(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    List<TankStats> users = new ArrayList<>();
    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("data")) {
            reader.beginObject();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                reader.beginArray();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    users.add(readTankId(reader));
                 }
                 reader.endArray();
            }
        }   
        else {
            reader.skipValue();
        }   
    }
    reader.endObject();
    return users;
}
```

I'm not really sure how to get around this error.

Comment: Where is your error? Can you post the stack trace and tell us which line is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check for the JSON

```
"data":{
```

with

```
if (name.equals("data")) {
```

Then consume the object in that name value pair with

```
reader.beginObject();
```

But then you do this

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    reader.beginArray();
```

while the token in the reader is

```
"1000194290":[
        {
```

You have to first consume the name before you consume the array.

Comment: to be more specific, `reader.nextName();` will return `"1000194290"` at this point.

Comment: adding reader.nextName(); beforereader.beginArray(); fixed it thanks

Comment: @user3581606 You're welcome. If the answer fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.